# Spent 10+ hours trying to fix issues with react-native init & ruby gems

Tags: ruby, react-native

When I run `npx react-native projectname`, the project is only created partially.

Now when I run `bundle install` I get:

`1. Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`2. An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that "gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'" succeeds before bundling.`

[image]

Yes, I have installed the ffi 1.15.5 (below screenshot) but it is still saying I dont have it

[image]

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]

**pod** --version: 1.11.3

I am impressed how difficult it is to start a project. Someone please help

Comment: please remove the screenshots of text ... add the text

Comment: @jsotola Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @5ecured same thing as saying `don't give me a picture of an apple, give me the apple` ... same with your text ... don't give us pictures of text

Answer (score 0):

Culprit would be that Xcode path is wrong.
Make sure there is valid Xcode then run this first.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: Will try your suggestion thank you.